# Android 7.1 - issues sending sms via adb

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to send mo sms via adb with all the examples I found on the internet but none worked for me. My two test phones use Android 7.1.2. Both has 1 sim inside. According to examples I found this should be the correct synthax depending on the id of the sim:

```
adb shell service call isms 7 i32 1 s16 "com.android.mms" s16 "+1234567890" s16 "null" s16 "Hey\ you\ !" s16 "null" s16 "null"

adb shell service call isms 7 i32 1 s16 "com.android.mms" s16 "+1234567890" s16 "null" s16 "Hey\ you\ !" s16 "null" s16 "null"

adb shell service call isms 7 i32 1 s16 "com.android.mms" s16 "+1234567890" s16 "null" s16 "Hey\ you\ !" s16 "null" s16 "null"

adb shell service call isms 7 i32 1 s16 "com.android.mms" s16 "+1234567890" s16 "null" s16 "Hey\ you\ !" s16 "null" s16 "null"
```

I tested with 0-3 and none worked. I am getting these two responses but actually it doesn't send anything:

```
Result: Parcel(
  0x00000000: fffffffc 00000023 00740041 00650074 '....#...A.t.t.e.'
  0x00000010: 0070006d 00200074 006f0074 00670020 'm.p.t. .t.o. .g.'
  0x00000020: 00740065 006c0020 006e0065 00740067 'e.t. .l.e.n.g.t.'
  0x00000030: 00200068 0066006f 006e0020 006c0075 'h. .o.f. .n.u.l.'
  0x00000040: 0020006c 00720061 00610072 00000079 'l. .a.r.r.a.y...')

Result: Parcel(00000000    '....')
```

Isms service is available.

I've sent smses via adb and other versions (5, 9, 11) of android without any issue.

Any idea what may be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make it work as described in documentation and other examples but I found a workaround for my google pixel test phones:

```
adb -s device_id shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:0044123456789 --es sms_body "testsms" --ez exit_on_sent true
sleep 2
adb -s device_id shell input keyevent 20
sleep 2
adb -s device_id shell input keyevent 22
sleep 2
adb -s device_id shell input keyevent 66
```